# Git merge as rebase / Cherry-pick whole branch

Tags: git, merge, rebase

What I want is inspired how GitHub handles merging Pull Requests which gives you 3 options:

1. "Create merge commit": i.e. `git checkout target && git merge source`
2. "Squash": i.e. `git checkout target && git merge --squash source`
3. "Rebase"

I'm already on the target branch and basically want the 3rd option which would be something like `git checkout source && git rebase target && git checkout target && git reset --hard source`. Alternatively the last step could also be `git merge --ff-only source`

So what I'd like to have is a `git merge --rebase source` that does **NOT**  modify the source. I just want to cherry-pick all commits from the source branch that are not in the target branch without needing to list them all.

The closest I could come up with is to create a temporary branch and delete it afterwards.

I think `git rebase --onto A B C` can be used, but am not sure how. E.g. `git rebase --onto target target source` as per documentation will:

- `git switch source`
- record `git log target..source` (commits in source not in target)
- `git reset --hard target`
- `git cherry-pick <recorded>`

Hence it will modify the source branch which is not what I want.
Very close is `git rebase --onto target source [target]` (last arg can be omitted if already on target) which would modify the target branch as required BUT with commits in target not in source, i.e. nothing.

Is there some way to apply to my current (i.e. target) branch commits from another branch that are not yet there as-if I cherry-picked them or rebased the source without actually modifying the source? I figure there's got to be one as Github offers that option. Of course they could as well just use a temporary.

Answer (score 0):

i guess i don't get the question completely.

so if you have checkout branch "target", then you could rebase all changes from another branch, let's say it's name is "source". of course a pre requirement is that they have a common base, f.e. find it out with:
`git merge-base head source`.

then if source is just a local branch do:
`git rebase source`. which would put all new (newer as merge-base) commits from source and then apply all your changes from "target" named branch.

which would take all the

if it's a remote branch from let's say repository origin then do:
`git pull --rebase origin source`

both scenarios will not touch the source named branch.

if this doesn't answer your question then please describe more explicit what your goal is you wan't to archive.

Comment: I want to have the effect of cherry-picking all "missing" commits from source to target. Rebasing the target puts the target on top of source rewriting the history such that I can't cleanly push it which is not what I want. I basically want to rebase, then merge the source. I tried to describe this in the question with the 4 commands under the first list

Comment: ok i guess i get it know. so if your target has a clean common base with source then IMO `git rebase --onto target source` should work, or alternatively `git rebase -i target` and then put the commits to above... BUT I wouldn't recommend to do so. This will only work once in a clear way. Afterwords your branches don't have a clean common baseline any more. So, if you don't want to change the history of target, you don't wan't a merge request. Then i really would go with manual cherry picks which you could of course rebase with `rebase -i [COMMIT BEFORE FIRST CHERRY PICK], to have it compacter.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question `git rebase --onto target source` is only almost what I want: It will update the current branch with commits in target not in source which are none. And `git rebase -i target` would need to be done on the source branch and hence modify that instead of the target